# How to write long readable innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, readability

I have a long block of HTML I have to assign to innerHTML (with some server-side ASP values added in the mix).

Are there any good practices for writing HTML in standard "nice" layout – e.g., with proper indents – in such a way that it can be assigned to innerHTML?

(We can't assume that a particular IDE or code editor will always be used.)

*As an example:* Here's a pattern I'm encountering often in code I'm refactoring:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
    window.opener.document.getElementById("overlay").style.position = "fixed";
    window.opener.document.getElementById("overlay").style.width = "700px";
    window.opener.document.getElementById("overlay").style.top = "100px";
    window.opener.document.getElementById("overlay").innerHTML = "<DIV STYLE=\"margin:25px 0px -10px 0px\"><DIV CLASS=\"error\" STYLE=\"height:auto; background:#ffe5e5; background-image:url(/images/icon_alert.png); background-position:5px 5px; background-repeat:no-repeat; border:1px solid #c00; -moz-border-radius:7px; -webkit-border-radius:7px; border-radius:7px; margin:10px 0px; padding:10px 10px 10px 35px; color:#c00\">There was a problem ... ;
```

Comment: If you're writing values to `innerHTML`, there's really no need to indent or format the markup as it will all be rendered the same way anyway.

Comment: @JustinNiessner - It's for the benefit of all us poor saps who have to work with the HTML.  Think of it as the opposite of minifying or obfuscating.

Comment: If you _have to_ programatically insert content, then `innerHTML` will probably rank among your worst options. One reason is that it's very easy to slip up and have a security vulnerability. Instead, just create the content programatically: `document.create("div")` for example and then manipulate it with`element.className = "myClass"` or whatever. jQuery will wrap the DOM manipulation in more concise forms but it'd do the same under the hood. It's probably even better to just have some templating library at play - way more easy on the eye and more maintainable then.

Comment: I believe the "problem" is trying to source the information (html, as text) into a JavaScript string.

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to use client-side templating, such as [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) along with jQuery. Then you can keep your HTML nicely formatted in individual .html files and completely separate from the rest of your code. Libraries like Handlebars also provide provisions to inject variables into templates.

Note that you will need to load your templates. In development mode, you can load these via HTTP request from the browser, or if you're using Grunt, Gulp, or webpack, you can build your templates into your JavaScript application file so that no additional HTTP requests are necessary. For production mode, you'll want to heavily consider building your templates into your app payload to minimize the number of HTTP requests.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

Always try to avoid innerHTML to an extent you can(by using createElement() or createFragment() or by toggling some visibility properties),

Don't ever do innerHTML, it will cause full layout and paint of your page and is literally equal to tree shaking.

Comment: Sounds like a decent TL;DR (except I'm stymied figuring out what the tree is that one might literally be shaking).  Now can you provide the substance?  I just updated the question with an example you could use.